# Connecting Android App to ASP Website Without web service

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, soap

Hi Every body I Have an ASP website
That Provides Login For Users
I want to Call that from Android App

 but I have no Experience in WCF
I don't want to use asp web service because this is "Classified Information"
any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Instead of linking your website login to your android application, make your site mobile-friendly (via CSS). Now create an WebView android app and link your whole website to this. Below link should help you -

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

By the way, Web service provides enough security to deliver classified information, I guess. As an extra layer of security, you can design your own encryption policy to secure the information delivered over network.